# Jquery-Jqgrid in MVC

Tags: jqgrid

I have a Jqgrid, and I am trying to show some fields on the grid, but when I Form Editing it, and show all Fields, which is having more columns than showing on the Grid.

For Example: I have a Document table, which have ID, Name,Size, Description, Date

on the Grid I only show ID, Name, and Size

when user click on the Edit, which is Form Editing, then let the users Edit all the Columns.

How can I do it?

Comment: Problem is solved but not marked the answer?

Answer (score 0):

well first you gotta put some code here, from what i can understand here, you have a grid with lets say 5 columns and when you want to go with form editing then you want to edit and show only 3 columns, right?   so what you need to do, put editable:false with your colModal

for example

{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', align: 'right', editable: false, hidden: true}

this will hide the Id column in grid and if you try to go for form editing Id will not be editable and it will not be there in edit form dialogue..